# Plotting an arrow with a thinning and fading tail

Tags: javascript, python, css, svg, plot

I’d like to create a static plot like this one that has arrows with fading and thinning tails:

https://googletrends.github.io/asne/?view=3

I have tried using Python libraries for this, but they are unable to replicate the combination of thinning (reduction of arrow tail width) and fading.
I’ve also tried some approaches in Matlab for this, but they were not successful. Would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: The linked page is using svg, so that is probably the way to go.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem. Is it the plotting you are having a problem with or the drawing of that type of arrow?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "Inspect Element" and tweaking. This is the SVG fragment for an arrow that I extracted from your example.

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px">
  <path class="arrow-scatter-line arrow-scatter-line-average" d="M221.35107316463535,190 L215.35107316463535,194 L215.35107316463535,191.5 L187.56800846984092,190 L215.35107316463535,188.5 L215.35107316463535,186 L221.35107316463535,190"  stroke="none" fill-opacity="1"></path>
</svg>
```